# How does one make compost tea?

Tags: compost, technique, compost-tea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make manure tea without e. coli](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/320/how-to-make-manure-tea-without-e-coli)

In [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/306/what-is-compost-tea-good-for), the benefits of compost tea were discussed. In short, it promotes growth, nourishes the plant and the soil, and helps keep diseases off. So how does one go about making compost tea at home? Does it require one to already have a compost heap/composting plan setup?